# How to Add rel="nofollow" in "Add new comment" link in teaser?

Tags: 7, hooks, comments

Is there a code to add rel="nofollow" in the "Add new comment" link under teaser?

This is the code in the teaser as generated by D7:

[Add new comment](/comment/reply/4293#comment-form)

So how I do I add rel="nofollow" in that line?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by implementing [`hook_node_view_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) in your custom module or theme.

```
//replace MODULENAME below with your custom module's name
function MODULENAME_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if ($build['#node']->type == 'book') {
    $build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add'] = "rel=\"nofollow\"";
  }
}
```

This is for node type *book*, you could replace it by the content type you are using.

Here is the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules), which should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in preprocess as well. Better to use structured data as its meant to be an not push attributes as strings, that will bound to create an error at some stage because theme_link() wants attribute arrays, not strings.

```
function themename_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
   if ($vars['node']->type == 'blog') {
    $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['attributes']['rel'][] = 'nofollow';
  }
}
```